# Convert to use dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have the following example code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public interface IPriceList
    {
        double GetPrice();
    }

    public class PriceList : IPriceList
    {
        public double GetPrice()
        {
            return 2.3;
        }
    }

    public interface ISensorValue
    {
        double GetValue();
    }

    public class SensorValue : ISensorValue
    {
        public double GetValue()
        {
            return 20.5;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Condition
    {
        public abstract bool IsTrue();

    }

    public class PriceCondition : Condition
    {
        private IPriceList _priceList;

        public PriceCondition(IPriceList priceList)
        {
            _priceList = priceList;
        }

        public override bool IsTrue() { return _priceList.GetPrice() > 4.4; }
    }

    public class SensorCondition : Condition
    {
        private ISensorValue _sensorValue;

        public SensorCondition(ISensorValue sensorValue)
        {
            _sensorValue = sensorValue;
        }

        public override bool IsTrue() { return _sensorValue.GetValue() > 20.4; }
    }

    public class ScheduleManager
    {
        private List<Condition> _conditions = new List<Condition>();

        public ScheduleManager(IPriceList priceList, ISensorValue sensorValue)
        {
            Condition condition = new PriceCondition(priceList);
            _conditions.Add(condition);
            condition = new SensorCondition(sensorValue);
            _conditions.Add(condition);
        }

    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PriceList priceList = new PriceList();
            SensorValue sensorValue = new SensorValue();
            ScheduleManager deviceScheduleManager = new ScheduleManager(priceList, sensorValue);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to convert this to using dependency injection with the following changes:

1. I don't want to pass any dependencies to ScheduleManager (they are only used to be be passed down to PriceCondition and SensorCondition. All the subclasses of Condition may have different set of dependencies and the number of dependencies which then needs to be passed through the constructor of ScheduleManager would become large. The dependencies needed by each Condition subclass should somehow be injected at that level.
2. The code in the ScheduleManager class which creates the two different Condition objects is just a simplified example. In the real case, Condition objects will be created dynamically based on the content of a JSON file.

Comment: Are `PriceList` and `SensorValue` services in this case? You show them as interfaces which tend to represent services, but the names look like data classes

Comment: They are typically not something like REST services. Typically also typically don't have different implementation, but represent the interface which an object need to implement in order to satisfy the object using the dependency. The would not only be data classes. Can contain other methods too.